# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping for JsonPatchDocument

Tags: .net, automapper

Trying to Map using the Automapper 10. This was working fine with 9.1.
Maps created-

```
CreateMap(typeof(JsonPatchDocument<>), typeof(JsonPatchDocument<>)).ReverseMap();
CreateMap(typeof(Operation<>), typeof(Operation<>)).ReverseMap()
```

Loading the maps as below

```
cfg.AddMaps(assemblyList);
cfg.AddProfiles(new List<Profile>(){new AutoMappingProfile()});
```

this is how I am mapping. entityType dynamically evaluated at run time.

```
var sourceType = jsonPatchDocument.GetType();
var destinationType = typeof(JsonPatchDocument<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
var method = GetMethod(nameof(Repository.Patch), new[] { entityType });
Mapper.Map(jsonPatchDocument, sourceType, destinationType);
```

This is throwing the following error

```
Test method Sfc.Wms.Data.UoW.Tests.Integration.DbUnitOfWorkTest.TestPatchByDictionary threw exception: 
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Object -> Object
System.Object -> System.Object
Stack Trace: 
    lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext )
    DbUnitOfWork.Patch[TDto](JsonPatchDocument`1 jsonPatchDocument) line 450
    DbUnitOfWork.Patch[TDto,TKey](TKey key, IDictionary`2 updateDictionary) line 431
    DbUnitOfWorkTest.TestPatchByDictionary() line 474
```

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail. Include _only_ the mapping part.